# How to add gradle native library (libelf) dependency in Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: c, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, elf

I am working on porting a pure c project onto android 5.1.1 API 22. The original project has Android.mk, which works fine. I followed [the guild](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) to port, but the newly created project is unable to correctly link the library libelf. I created a new module, trying to link libelf by using gradle. here is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path '../MyProject/Android.mk'
        }
    }
} // android

// The dependencies block is a part of the standard Gradle configuration (that is why it is placed outside of the android block)
// and defines all dependencies for an app or library. By default, a new Android app has a dependency on all the JAR files in
// the libs directory. Depending on the options you select in the new project wizard,
// it might also depend on the AppCompat library.
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In the AOSP, I can see the header file is in:  `external/elfutils/0.153/libelf`

Anyone knows the correct way to add the library libelf dependency in the gradle?

---

Here are the errors I got:

```
Error:(43) undefined reference to `elf_version'
Error:(54) undefined reference to `elf_begin'
Error:(60) undefined reference to `elf_kind'
Error:(64) undefined reference to `elf_getshdrstrndx'
Error:(65) undefined reference to `elf_errno'
Error:(65) undefined reference to `elf_errmsg'
Error:(56) undefined reference to `elf_errno'
Error:(56) undefined reference to `elf_errmsg'
Error:(117) undefined reference to `elf_end'
Error:(71) undefined reference to `elf_nextscn'
Error:(83) undefined reference to `elf64_getshdr'
Error:(90) undefined reference to `elf_strptr'
Error:(97) undefined reference to `elf_getdata'
Error:(85) undefined reference to `elf_errno'
Error:(85) undefined reference to `elf_errmsg'
Error:(92) undefined reference to `elf_errno'
Error:(92) undefined reference to `elf_errmsg'
Error:(99) undefined reference to `elf_errno'
Error:(99) undefined reference to `elf_errmsg'
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

**Build environment:**
System:Ubuntu 16.04: LTS
Android Studio version: 2.2.2
Android Plugin version: 2.2.2
Gradle version: 2.14.1

**Target android info:**
Android version: 5.1.1
API level: 22

---

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Do a clean build.you can probably do this fine in Android Studio, but to make sure I navigated in a terminal to the root folder of my app and typed `gradlew clean`

Comment: It does not work, I added the error message in the original post. Either the new native ndk-build has some problems (I think the android studio does parse the Android.mk correctly by some reason) or I did do it right.